# Get the duration of multiple videos with pure JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, html5-video

I am working on a project, and one of my tasks is to get the video duration of multiple videos that load in an iframe pop-up window.

To achieve that I have created two functions.

**Note:** Please keep in mind that these are stripped-down versions of the functions. The functions serve some other purposes as well.

```
const calculateVideo = (videoNodeList) => {
  let videoDurationTotal = 0;
  return videoDurationTotal == 0 || isNaN(videoDurationTotal) ? getTotalVideosDuration(videoNodeList) : videoDurationTotal;
};
```

And

```
const getTotalVideosDuration = (videoNodeList, videoDurationTotal) => {
  videoNodeList.forEach((videoNode, index) => {  
    
// This works sometimes
videoDurationTotal += videoNode.duration * 1000;

// This works always but the latency added is breaking the code
    videoNode.onloadedmetadata = (event) => {videoDurationTotal += videoNode.duration * 1000;};
  });
  return videoDurationTotal;
};
```

Now the above will return the correct value of time, but sometimes, it will not. I am not able to reproduce the issue 100% of the times. The problem is that the video metadata are not ready when the `getTotalVideosDuration` is called, so the values returned are `NaN`.

In order to fix that I tried to use `videoNode.onloadedmetadata = (event) => {};`. This seems to fix the issue with the `NaN` results, but it returns `0` which is the initial value. I believe the issue is that it adds some delay, and the code keeps executing.

How can get the total amount of time from the videos every time, without having the above issues?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could create some promises that resolve when metadata is loaded, and run code that does something with an array of durations when the promises resolve, example:

```js
const getTotalVideosDuration = (videoNodeList, videoDurationTotal) => {
  const promises = videoNodeList.map(videoNode => new Promise((resolve) => {
    videoNode.onloadedmetadata = (event) => resolve(videoNode.duration * 1000);
  }));
  
  Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
    // result should be an array of durations
    // do something with it here
    // don't attempt to "return" something from getTotalVideosDuration
    // unless you know how to await promises
    console.log(result);
  });
 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's what I had in mind too, but I am not very familiar with promises and async, but it seems like the only way to go.

The code you posted works great, but my problem is that I need to return the total time. Having it calculated inside the `then` will not work for my case.